# Overriding UITableView scrolling functionality

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I am trying to create a card style dashboard. Here is a sketch of what the dashboard will look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zf3W1.jpg

The way the interaction should work is that each of the individual cards are scrollable table views. If you are at the top of the tableview of the current card and you pull down it will physically move the view and bring the next one down.

My main issue is getting the table view to scroll conditionally and then move down at other times. I tried a few things and have been unsuccessful. My first attempt was to override scrollViewDidScroll for the UITableView like so:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

    if(self.lastContentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.y){
        if (self.isAtTop) {
            NSLog(@"is at top");
            if(scrollView.contentOffset.y <= 0){

                NSLog(@"less than or equal to zero");

                CGFloat value = scrollView.contentOffset.y*-1;
                [self.delegate pannedToYPosition:value];

                CGPoint newCenter = CGPointMake(self.previousLocationInSuperview.x,self.previousLocationInSuperview.y+1);
                self.center = newCenter;
                self.previousLocationInSuperview = newCenter;
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        self.atTop = NO;
    }
    self.lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
}
```

This doesn't work because it also scrolls the content in the table view down, simultaneously, as the view is being moved down.

Another thing I tried was to add a pan gesture recognizer over the table view and sometimes forward the pan events to the table view's "setContentOffset" but the problem that presented was losing the inertial scrolling and the rubber banding effect at the top of views.

What do you guys recommended? Do I need to somehow subclass UITableView? Thanks!

Comment: I really don't think your TableView is your solution. You need to work on Container Views Controllers with Scrolling and 3d Transformations. You should look into that. Tableview as far as i know doesn't have 3d transformations embedded in it.

Comment: in http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/StreetScroller/Introduction/Intro.html they overwrite layoutSubviews to do the positioning while scrolling. maybe you can do that with your tableviews and only call [super layoutSubviews] if the contentOffset.y >= 0. that could fix the issues with your first try.